# crystal reports conditional record selection with formulas

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal 2011.

In the view `Days_Lost` there is a calculated field `Percent`. I'd like to be able to list these by year and reason per employee.

```
Employee name | percent days 2017/18 Sickness|  percent days 2016/17 Sickness |2015/16 Sickness percent days 2017/18 other etc
```

I've linked `employee.emp_ID` to `Days_Lost.emp_ID` using a left link.

I tried formula

```
if {VIEW_DAYS_LOST.YEAR}="2017/2018" and {VIEW_DAYS_LOST.REASON}="Sick" then
if not isnull ({VIEW_DAYS_LOST.PERCENT}) then {VIEW_DAYS_LOST.PERCENT}
```

This gives the right results but I get duplicate employee rows.

I'm avoiding doing it in sql as not at all proficient and there are lots of other data tables that will need to be brought in to give other measures.

I don't have anything in record select formulas yet but was hoping to do a filter there after getting basic detail right.

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Database" option in Menu bar then click on "Select Distinct records" only. it will displays only distinct records.